# Azure storage account throws HTTP 400 error when writing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've developed a simple Azure Webapp with C#. And use the table of Azure storage account to save some kinds of records of the website.

It works well on my own computer on both read and write operations, with the real connection string. I can find the record with the "Azure Storage Explorer".

However, after I deploy the app. The cloud version keeps throwing Http 400 error when I try to write the table. But the read operation still works fine. (The local version is always OK.)

[image]

The problem is wierd. Please help me with it.

Thanks.

== UPDATE ==

The save & query code is something like this.

```
public class CodeSnippet: TableEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public Guid Save()
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var datetime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        this.RowKey = guid.ToString();
        this.PartitionKey = datetime.ToString();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);

        var client = AzureStorage.DefaultClient.Instance.GetTableClient();
        var table = client.GetTableReference("privateshare");
        var insertOp = TableOperation.Insert(this);

        table.Execute(insertOp);
        return guid;
    }

    public static CodeSnippet Query(Guid? guid)
    {
        if (guid == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var client = AzureStorage.DefaultClient.Instance.GetTableClient();
        var table = client.GetTableReference("privateshare");

        var query = new TableQuery<CodeSnippet>()
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(
                "RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, guid.ToString()))
            .Take(1);
        var res = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
        return res?.First();
    }
}
```

Comment: 400 error usually means there's something wrong with the data that you're trying to write. Can you share the data that you're trying to write when your app is deployed in the cloud? Also, it would be helpful if you can share the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The error occurs when I take `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString()` as the partition key.

After I change it to `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()`, it eventually works fine.

I don't know how & why the problem happens. But I guess the special characters in the "PartitionKey" may be the reason of the problem.

Comment: `But I guess the special characters in the "PartitionKey" may be the reason of the problem.` --> This is exactly the problem. When you convert date/time to string, it writes it in `mm/dd/yyyy` format which has `/` character in it and this is not allowed character for PartitionKey value. Please see my answer here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589493/query-execution-on-azure-storage-is-very-slow/36589742#36589742.

Comment: @GauravMantri But the local version works perfectly fine.(sad)   The date string doesn't contain the character '/'. Maybe it's ':', '+' or the whitespace who cause the problem.